# php preg_match to find <img> tag but not with gif extension

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I know how to find an img tag within a string but I need to exclude any img tag with gif extension in it. How do I use the negative in my preg_match? I only need the first image tag which does not contain .gif extension.

I currently have this:

```
  $text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  $pattern = "/<img[^>]+\>/i";
  preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
  $text = $matches[0];
```

$text will give me the first  tag, for e.g. `<img src="something.gif" border="0" />`
However, I do not want to accept .gif, so if the first  is a gif, it will skip it and continue searching for other .

Please advise me how to change my code to it.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it that way. Attempting to parse HTML with regex is a task doomed to failure, since  a slight increase in the complexity of the HTML or the requirement will make your regex unbelievably complicated.

The best way is to use a tool designed for the task: the `DOMDocument` class.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($text);

$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if (!substr($image->getAttribute('src'), -4) === '.gif') {
        break;
    }
}

// $image is now the first image that didn't end with .gif
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Talking about domdocument, is it possible for me to find out the width of the image? Let's say I want to exclude .gif and any image that is less than 200px in width. I know that I can probably do getAttribute('width') but people may not have the width attribute or the actual size may be biger. Is there a way to find out the actual width of the image?

Comment: @user2082532 Not without loading the image using an image library.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your pattern to something like this if you still want to use regular expression.

```
<?php
$text = '<img src="something.jpg" ';
$pattern = '/<img\s+src="(([^"]+)(.)(jpeg|png|jpg))"/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $out);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
?>
```

Comment: And what about `<img border="0" src="something.png" />`?

Comment: it can be justified for this also :), my pattern is just for showing that extensions should be white-listed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php
$text = '<img src="something.jpg" ';

preg_match('/src="(?P<image>.*\.(jpeg|png|jpg))"/', $text, $matches);

echo $matches['image'];
?>
```

Comment: Your regex will match `.gif` extension.